# Filter from table where entries are populated using coma(,) through checkbox php my sl

Tags: php, mysql

Hello all Iam just a newone on coding php mysql.In a very short of time i am trying to test a phpmysql filter,like what we now see on different ecommerce sites.But at a point iam glued where I have a table of selective cuisine lists eg:the table[cuisine_view][1]. I have insert those values through implode(). I would like to filter those Rest_ids where rest_cuisine=CHINESE.Here at the query i have used the "find_in_set" tag to search for a particular string from a list of strings separated by ,(coma).

Here is my form of checkbox.

```
<form method="post" action="cuisine_view.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>SELECT CUISINS:</P><br>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="INDIAN">INDIAN
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="CHINESE">CHINESE
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="CONTINENTAL">CONTINENTAL
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="REGIONAL">REGIONAL
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="BENGALI">BENGALI
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="SOUTHINDIAN">SOUTHINDIAN
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="NORTHINDIAN">NORTHINDIAN
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="BIRIYANI">BIRIYANI
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="MOGLAI">MOGLAI
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="KEBAB">KEBAB
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="PIZZA">PIZZA
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="BURGER">BURGER
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="SANDWITCH AND SALADS">SANDWITCH AND SALADS
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="DIETFOOD">DIETFOOD
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="ICE-CREAMS">ICE-CREAMS
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="COFEE AND TEA">COFEE AND TEA
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="SWEETS AND SNACKS">SWEETS AND SNACKS
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="FRIED CHICKEN">FRIED CHICKEN
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="MOMOS AND SOUP">MOMOS AND SOUP
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="MOKTALES">MOKTALES
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="CHOCOLATES">CHOCOLATES
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="BAKERY">BAKERY
    </div>
    <div class="cb-row">
        <input type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="CAKES">CAKES
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" >
</form>





......................
And the php mysql query : 
...after successfull db connection...`$checkbox = implode(',', $_POST['answer']);
$sql = "SELECT Rest_id FROM vendor_filter WHERE find_in_set("$checkbox",Rest_cuisine)";
```

`
       But its not working saying error msg as:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$checkbox' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\templetes\cuisine_view.php 
    I am stucked...please enlight me..with regards.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v44iC.png
```

Comment: You should not do this. Instead, use a different table to connect your checkboxes to your filter. A normalized table is a lot easier to search in and manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
$sql = "SELECT Rest_id FROM vendor_filter WHERE 1=1 ";
foreach($_POST['answer'] as $val){
$sql .=" and find_in_set($val,Rest_cuisine)";//AND|OR what you want 
}
```

> [Find_in_set](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) Returns a value in the range of 1 to N if the string
>   str is in the string list strlist consisting of N substrings

Comment: i have used the code like this but it goes to the else part where result Unsuccesfull...$sql = "SELECT Rest_id FROM vendor_filter";
      foreach($_POST['answer'] as $val)
      {
      $sql .="find_in_set($val,Rest_cuisine)";
      }
      echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if($result)
     {
      echo "YOUR CUISINE"; 
     while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
      echo $row[Rest_id]; //for example
     echo "go to menu page";
      echo "<a href=menu.php>MENU</a>";
      }  
     }
   
   else
   {
     echo "UNSUCCESSFULL";
   }

Comment: Try this code $sql = "SELECT Rest_id FROM vendor_filter where 1=1 "; 
foreach($_POST['answer'] as $val) 
{ 
$sql .=" OR find_in_set($val,Rest_cuisine)"; 
} 
echo $sql; 
$result = mysqli_num_rows($sql); 
if($result) 
{ 
echo "YOUR CUISINE"; 
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{ 
echo $row[Rest_id]; 
//for example echo "go to menu page"; 
echo "<a href=menu.php>MENU</a>"; 
} 
} 
else 
{ 
echo "UNSUCCESSFULL"; 
}